# Anytime Upgrade by buying a retail box

Tags: windows-7

I am looking at buying a retail copy of [Windows 7 Professional Upgrade](http://www.software4students.co.uk/products/microsoft-windows-7-professional-upgrade). Is it possible to use [Windows Anytime Upgrade](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/shop/windows-anytime-upgrade) with the product key I get on the box to upgrade from Home Premium to Professional?

Comment: Aren't the Windows 7 Upgrade Options mentioned on that page, including which combinations support In-Place Upgrades, and which require Custom (Clean) Installs?

Comment: it does but doesnt mention anything about win7 on the table the overveiw suggests it is possible but is really unclear

Comment: Win 7 are the four columns across the top. Match your current OS with the row on the right with the column representing the version of Win 7 you want to upgrade to.

Comment: sorry im not quite making myself clear i want to know if i can do a windows anytime upgrade from premium to professional with the licence key that comes with http://www.software4students.co.uk/products/microsoft-windows-7-professional-upgrade

Comment: You'll probably just want to get a hold of them and ask if you want to be perfectly sure.  Have them send you an email stating that it's possible.  Good to have a "paper" trail in case it doesn't work.